# Check if document already exists and if yes then update, otherwise create new - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have app where I am trying to check whether a document with the users ID already exists, if yes then update the existing one with the data sent in the request if it does not exist then create a new document.

**I have done this so far:**

```
Bio.findOne({userID: req.body.userID}, function(err, bio) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("The error while updating colleciton is " + err);
        }
        // if already exists then update it
        if (bio) {
            console.log("Bio document for user already exists!");
            bio.userBios = {
                $push: {
                    background: req.body.userBios.background,
                    experience: req.body.userBios.experience,
                    skills: req.body.userBios.skills,
                    bioForSector: req.body.userBios.bioForSector
                }
            }
            bio.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err
                return (null, bio)
            })
        }
        //if does not exist then create new 
        if (!bio) {
            console.log("Bio document for user does NOT exist! creating new");
            var bio = new Bio();

            bio.firstName = req.body.firstName;
            bio.lastName = req.body.lastName;
            bio.jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;
            bio.userID = req.body.userID;
            bio.userBios = {
                background: req.body.userBios.background,
                experience: req.body.userBios.experience,
                skills: req.body.userBios.skills,
                bioForSector: req.body.userBios.bioForSector
            };

            // save the bio
            bio.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                return (null, bio);
            });
        }
    });
```

**The issue:**

I can successfully create a new document but when I try to update it, it overwrites the whole `userBios` array rather then updating it.

**My Document Schema:**

```
// define the schema for our bios model
 var biosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     firstName: String,
     lastName: String,
     jobTitle: String,
     userID: String,
     userBios: [{bioForSector: String, background: String, skills: [String], experience: {}}]
     });
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help? it'll be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by _overwrites the whole document_ ? Which condition is getting satisfied ?

Comment: @RayonDabre When the user create new document it contains the `background, skills, experience` for the first bio but when the user updates it rather then pushing the new `background, skills, experience` as a new object in the `userBios` array within the schema it overwrites the previous one with all null data. Meaning  the `background, skills, experience` variables in database are changed to `null`. does this help?

Comment: @RayonDabre I changed my wording a bit, I mean it overwrites the whole `userbios` array rather then updating it by pushing a new object into it.

Comment: Just push a new item into `bio.userBios`: `bio.userBios.push(userBiosObject)`. And use callbacks or promises in `bio.save()`

Comment: @AlexanderMac thanks for the tip mate, that worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alexander Mac says in the comments, you are overriding the array yourself. If the document exists, try:

```
if (bio) {
    console.log("Bio document for user already exists!");
    bio.userBios.push({
        background: req.body.userBios.background,
        experience: req.body.userBios.experience,
        skills: req.body.userBios.skills,
        bioForSector: req.body.userBios.bioForSector
    });
    bio.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err
        return (null, bio)
    });
}
```

This way you really push it in an existing array instead of creating a new one.