# MongoDB save() creating new document each time rather than updating existing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, put, upsert

I'm using this function to save to mongodb:

```
create(req, res, next) {
  let data = req.body;
  if(data) {
    let newIssue = this.lib.db.model('Issues')('data');
    console.log(newIssue);
    newIssue.save((err, emp) => {
      if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
      this.writeHAL(res, emp);
    });
  } else {
    next(this.RESTError('InvalidArgumentError', 'No data received'));
  }
}
```

This is my schema:

```
module.exports = {
  "id": "Issues",
  "properties": {
    "issue_title": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The title of the issue"
    },
    "issue_number": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The issue number"
    },
    "issue_url": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "URL of the issue"
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding of `save()` is that if the document already exists in mongodb it gets updated but a new one is created if it doesn't already exist. However, each time I POST the same document, a new document is inserted rather than the existing one getting updated. I have a suspicion this is because when saving, an `_id` key containing a unique ID is added to my schema making the document unique. Is this correct and if so how do I resolve this?

**Additional info**

I've now added a PUT. the idea is that I would do an update with `{upsert:true}`. I've it partially working in that I can PUT to `issue/{id} where`{id}`is the mongodb`_id` and update existing documents.

This is my PUT:

```
update(req, res, next) {
  let data = req.body;
  let id = req.params.id;
  if(id) {
    this.lib.db.model('Issues')
      .findOne({_id: id})
      .exec((err, updateIssue) => {
        if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
        updateIssue = Object.assign(updateIssue, data);
        updateIssue.update((err, issue) => {
          if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
          this.writeHAL(res, issue);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

This is the routing:

```
    controller.addAction({
      'path': '/issues/{id}',
      'method': 'PUT',
      'summary': "UPDATES the issues's information",
      'params': [swagger.pathParam('id', 'The id of the issue', 'string'),
    swagger.bodyParam('issue', 'the new information to update', 'string')],
      'responseClass': 'Issues',
      'nickname': 'updateIssue'
    }, controller.update);
```

I don't think I can use this for upsert as I have no `_id` to begin with so can;t create the path. My other option is to use the `github_id`. however any time I try to cahnge my routing path to `/issues/{github_id}` or update my function with something like `.findOne({github_id: id})` I get an error. I need to be able to use `/issues/{github_id}` and for the check to see if the `github_id` already exists. If it does, update the document, if not, create a new one.

**Further info.**

I've changed my update function to:

```
update(req, res, next) {
  let data = req.body;
  let id = req.params.id;
  if(id) {
    this.lib.db.model('Issues')
      .findOne({_id: id})
      .exec((err, updateIssue) => {
        if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
        updateIssue = Object.assign(updateIssue, data);
        updateIssue.update({_id: id}, data, (err, issue) => {
          if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
          this.writeHAL(res, issue);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

If I add the following `console.log`'s after line `updateIssue.update({_id: id}, data, (err, issue) => {`:

```
console.log('id: ', id);
console.log('data: ', data);
console.log('err: ', err);
console.log('issue: ', issue);
```

I get this output:

```
id:  5b80307403eea4f14b06fe8c
data:  { _id: '5b80307403eea4f14b06fe8c',
  github_id: '347593262',
  issue_title: 'test issue XY',
  issue_number: '2',
  issue_url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/PCTestOrg/test1/issues/2a',
  __v: 0 }
err:  null
issue:  { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

I expect `issue_title` to be updated from `test issue X` to `test issue XY`, however the update does not happen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: MongoDB use internally "_id" to check if the document exists into the database. If no "_id" is provided, then a new _id is created from the driver and an insert is made into the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get upsert working so ended up with the below after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546791/check-if-document-already-exists-and-if-yes-then-update-otherwise-create-new?rq=1) post:

```
update(req, res, next) {
  let data = req.body;
  let id = req.params.id;
  if(id) {
    this.lib.db.model('Issues')
      .findOne({_id: id})
      .exec((err, updateIssue) => {
        if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
        updateIssue = Object.assign(updateIssue, data);
        updateIssue.save((err, issue) => {
          if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
          this.writeHAL(res, issue);
        });
      });
  }
  else if(data) {
    let newIssue = this.lib.db.model('Issues')(data);
    console.log(newIssue);
    newIssue.save((err, issue) => {
      if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
      this.writeHAL(res, issue);
    });
  } else {
    next(this.RESTError('InvalidArgumentError', 'No data received'));
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do it if anybody can show me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do create or update use Update with [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter)

```
Model.update({_id: id}, obj, {upsert: true}, function (err) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Sharma. I'm trying to think how I might do this. I'm currently using newIssue.save. The data is getting routed to my function from a POST to `/issues`. I would have to instead use a PUT to `issues/{issue_id}`, which would get routed to a function using update with upsert enabled. Is that correct or is there a simpler way?